Hibernate Entity Mapping Child Only Contains Child Lists
I call a REST API and receive some JSON back (example below). I am using Jackson to convert the JSON to POJOs successfully, but I’m having troubles figuring out how to save ALL of the created entities to the DB using Hibernate. My code is successfully saving Announcement entity to the DB. I’m not sure how to handle announcementExternalIDs as there is nothing to save to the DB, but it contains lists of data that does need saved (announcementCustomerIDs, announcementOfficeIDs, and announcementPositionIDs).
My DB schema is up to me. Right now, I have DB tables for Announcement, AnnouncementCustomerIDs, AnnouncementOfficeIDs, and announcementPositionIDs.
{
    " announcementData ": [
        {
            "departmentId": 1,
            "announcementId": 12345,
            "announcementNumber": "Test Ann",
            "announcementExternalIDs": {
                "announcementCustomerIDs": [
                    {
                        "departmentId": 1,
                        "announcementId": 12345,
                        "customerId": 111
                    }
                ],
                "announcementOfficeIDs": [
                    {
                        "departmentId": 1,
                        "announcementId": 12345,
                        "officeId": 1
                    }
                ],
                "announcementPositionIDs": [
                    {
                        "departmentId": 1,
                        "announcementId": 12345,
                        "positionId": 98765
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}

Current DB tables.
**AnnouncementData**
- AnnouncementID, NUMBER (PK)
- departmentId, NUMBER
- AnnouncementNumber, VARCHAR2(30)

**AnnouncementCustomerIDs**
- AnnouncementID, NUMBER
- CustomerID, NUMBER
- departmentId, NUMBER

**AnnouncementOfficeIDs**
- AnnouncementID, NUMBER
- OfficeID, NUMBER
- departmentId, NUMBER

**AnnouncementPositionIDs**
- AnnouncementID, NUMBER
- PositionID, NUMBER
- departmentId, NUMBER

@Entity
@Table(name = "ANNOUNCEMENT")
public class Announcement {
  @Id
  @JsonProperty("announcementId")
  private long announcementId;

  @JsonProperty("departmentId")
  private int departmentId;

  @JsonProperty("announcementNumber")
  private String announcementNumber;

  @JsonProperty("announcementExternalIDs")
  private AnnouncementExternalIds announcementExternalIDs;

@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@JsonPropertyOrder({"announcementCustomerIDs", "announcementOfficeIDs", "announcementVacancyIDs"})
public class AnnouncementExternalIds {
  @JsonProperty("announcementCustomerIDs")
  private List<AnnouncementCustomerId> announcementCustomerIds = new ArrayList<>();

  @JsonProperty("announcementOfficeIDs")
  private List<AnnouncementOfficeId> announcementOfficeIds = new ArrayList<>();

  @JsonProperty("announcementPositionIDs")
  private List<AnnouncementPositionID> announcementPositionIDs= new ArrayList<>();

@Entity
@Table(name = "ANNOUNCEMENT_CUSTOMER_ID")
public class AnnouncementCustomerId {
  @JsonProperty("departmentId")
  private String departmentId;

  @JsonProperty("announcementId")
  private String announcementId;

  @Id
  @JsonProperty("customerId")
  private String customerId;

I understand the current error shown below. It's because I don't have class AnnouncementExternalIds mapped to as an entity to a DB table. But it doesn't need saved to DB.
org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: AnnouncementExternalIds, at table: ANNOUNCEMENT, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(announcementExternalIDs)]

First of all you have to use DTO pattern here to get the request. Refer this link and what is departmentId here?

I'll take a look at that link, thank you. As for departmentId, I'm not completely sure to be honest. I believe value will stay the same for my organization.

FYI, this application has no users and no GUI
